# how to cite from science direct in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, back-referencing

I want to cite following  article

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054804000711

I want to know how should I cite it in following format

```
@article{dhanl,
    author={Y. Dhanalakshmi, and I. Ramesh Babu},
    title={“Intrusion detection using data
    mining along fuzzy logic and genetic algorithms,”}
    journal={International Journal
    of Computer Science \& Security},
    volume=  {8},
    issue={2},
    pages= {27–32}, 
    year={2008}
}
```

also in bibliography I see @article , @web what does this thing beginning with @ means is it pre defined or we can use it in what ever way we can?

Comment: The thing beginning with `@` is the *entry type* of your `.bib` entry. The list of supported entry types will depend on the style you use, but most styles support a core set of types, amongst which are `@article`, `@book`, `@incollection`.

Comment: is this thing defined some where like what should we use what should we not use and what is standard to use

Comment: This is a bit tricky. A core set of entry types and fields is documented in the BIbTeX user documentation [`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf), but many styles support a few more types and fields than those listed there. For example many modern styles have fields for DOIs and URLs (usually called `doi` and `url`). So ultimately, you need to check the documentation of the style you use.

Comment: ok thats is great I thought we can arbitrarily make a tag of our own and tag things like we like.

Comment: In theory you can use arbitrary types and field names, but if a style doesn't know the type you use it will usually just fall back to assuming you meant `@misc` and it will ignore any fields it doesn't know.

Comment: Note that usually one should not include formatting like `“` and `”` in fields if the markup is included to format the entire field. Trailing punctuation like the comma in `title={“Intrusion detection using data mining along fuzzy logic and genetic algorithms,”}` is also usually a bad idea.

Comment: ok I was looking for this information also like putting `,` or `" "` in my questions , I was trying to understand how this is working.